Vert.x use localstorage
is there a way to use the localstorage-function of a browser using vert.x?
router.route().handler(SessionHandler.create(LocalSessionStore.create(vertx)));
        router.get("/set").handler(ctx -> {
            ctx.session().put("key", "value");
            ctx.response().end("Session value set");
        });
        router.get("/get").handler(ctx -> {
            String value = ctx.session().get("key");
            ctx.response().end("Session value: " + value);
        });

seems to use a backend-hashmap - not the browser-build-in function.
Browser-Function-Image

localStorage is a key-value store in the browser. In contrast, LocalSessionStore is a store on the server.
If you want to process a value from a user's localStorage on the server, you would need to grab the value via JavaScript and send it to the server.
Likewise, if you want the server to update a value in the user's localStorage, you would need to return the updated value back from the server (or just send it via SSE or WebSocket) and use JavaScript to put the updated value into the localStorage.
